# Converting xml to json in Golang

Tags: json, go, xml-to-json

I'm using [github.com/basgys/goxml2json](https://github.com/basgys/goxml2json) for xml to json conversion. Below is the example code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
    xj "github.com/basgys/goxml2json"
)

func main() {
    xml := strings.NewReader(`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <osm version="0.6" generator="CGImap 0.0.2">
     <bounds minlat="54.0889580" minlon="12.2487570" maxlat="54.0913900" maxlon="12.2524800"/>
     <foo>bar</foo>
    </osm>`)

    json, err := xj.Convert(xml)
    if err != nil {
        panic("ERROR converting xml to json")
    }

    fmt.Println(json.String())
}
```

The output of the above code is:

```
  {
    "osm": {
      "-version": 0.6,
      "-generator": "CGImap 0.0.2",
      "bounds": {
        "-minlat": "54.0889580",
        "-minlon": "12.2487570",
        "-maxlat": "54.0913900",
        "-maxlon": "12.2524800"
      },
      "foo": "bar"
    }
  }
```

However, I am expecting the output like below as given by https://codebeautify.org/xmltojson/y2221f265:

```
{
  "osm": {
    "bounds": "",
    "foo": "bar"
  }
}
```

How to remove the keys starting with `-` from the JSON output? I do not know the structure of the data beforehand.

Comment: Do you need a generic converter like this library or do you know the structure of the date you wish to convert? If you know the structure, defining a custom struct with https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/xml#Unmarshal might be easiest. It seems this library has plugins which can help customize how to convert but it seems that ignoring attributres might not be that easy https://github.com/basgys/goxml2json/blob/master/plugins.go.

Comment: Hi @DylanReimerink, as per my requirement I do not know the structure beforehand. So I have to work with generic converter like this library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should do it. It is a modified version of the `goxml2json.Convert` func. Used the `WithAttrPrefix` to specify a custom prefix(in case you ever want to use a - at the start of your body).

Please note that this only works for the latest commit on the master branch, the `v1.1.0` tag doesn't support plugins, so you have to go get it like so: `go get github.com/basgys/goxml2json@master`

`RemoveAttr` just recursively deletes all children with the given prefix. You could also do other modifications at this point.

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "strings"

    xj "github.com/basgys/goxml2json"
)

const prefix = "veryuniqueattrprefix-"

func main() {
    xml := strings.NewReader(`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <osm version="0.6" generator="CGImap 0.0.2">
     <bounds minlat="54.0889580" minlon="12.2487570" maxlat="54.0913900" maxlon="12.2524800"/>
     <foo>bar</foo>
    </osm>`)

    // Decode XML document
    root := &xj.Node{}
    err := xj.NewDecoder(
        xml,
        xj.WithAttrPrefix(prefix),
    ).Decode(root)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    RemoveAttr(root)

    // Then encode it in JSON
    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
    e := xj.NewEncoder(buf)
    err = e.Encode(root)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(buf.String())
}

func RemoveAttr(n *xj.Node) {
    for k, v := range n.Children {
        if strings.HasPrefix(k, prefix) {
            delete(n.Children, k)
        } else {
            for _, n := range v {
                RemoveAttr(n)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

outputs:

```
{"osm": {"bounds": "", "foo": "bar"}}
```

Comment: Thank you @Dylan. I have one doubt, why have you declared `const prefix = "veryuniqueattrprefix-"` instead of `const prefix = "-"`.

Comment: @Avinash I thought that might be nessesery to avoid conflicts, but seeing as using a - in xml tags is rare, this shouldn't be that big of an issue

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "strings"

    xj "github.com/basgys/goxml2json"
)

// ToObject - convert string to any given struct
func ToObject(value string, object interface{}) error {
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(value), &object)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
func main() {
    xml := strings.NewReader(`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <osm version="0.6" generator="CGImap 0.0.2">
     <bounds minlat="54.0889580" minlon="12.2487570" maxlat="54.0913900" maxlon="12.2524800"/>
     <foo>bar</foo>
    </osm>`)

    converter, err := xj.Convert(xml)
    if err != nil {
        panic("ERROR converting xml to json")
    }
    osmStruct := &ExampleStruct{}
    ToObject(converter.String(), &osmStruct)

    b, _ := json.Marshal(osmStruct)
    fmt.Println(string(b))
}

// ExampleStruct -
type ExampleStruct struct {
    Osm Osm `json:"osm"`
}

// Osm -
type Osm struct {
    Version   string `json:",omitempty"`
    Generator string `json:",omitempty"`
    Bounds    Bounds `json:"bounds"`
    Foo       string `json:"foo"`
}

// Bounds -
type Bounds struct {
    Minlat string `json:",omitempty"`
    Minlon string `json:",omitempty"`
    Maxlat string `json:",omitempty"`
    Maxlon string `json:",omitempty"`
}
```

Comment: Hi @SantoshAnand, Thank you for your answer. But as per my requirement I do not know the structure beforehand. That is the reason I'm using a generic converter like this library.